# SSH-Connection through gateway nc not working

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, gateway, putty, netcat

I have the following problem:
I want to connect from a Windows 7 client to a remote Debian 7 Server via an SSH Gateway running on a SLES 11.3 Server.
To test the connection I use plink with the following command

```
plink.exe root@<gatewayserver ip> -nc <destination server ip >:22
```

I can login on the gateway but after that i just get a prompt saying:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
```

My sshd_config on the gateway server

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
UsePriviligeSeparation yes
AllowAgentForwarding yes
Protocol 2
```

My ssh_config on the gateway server

```
Host <Dest Server ip range>
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
ForwardAgent yes
EscapeChar none
Protocol 2
```

My sshd_config on the destination server

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
Protocol 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would use something like this:

```
plink.exe -L 2222:[destination_server_ip]:22 root@[gatewayserver] -N
plink.exe root@127.0.0.1 -P 2222
```

the first one creates an SSH tunnel and opens a local port [2222] which is forwarded to the destination server

EDIT:
what you did was just something like

```
telnet 1.2.3.4 22
```

which just opened the port, and waited for you to talk SSH into the console (with in your case you want putty(plink) to do for you ;)

Comment: I have never used this kind of setup. but i assume you got something wrong with your authentication (according to the last two lines of your link) -> As long as you have your public key installed on the proxy and the host that you are connecting to, and your key is loaded into pageant, This will work.

Please note that it is necessary to have publickey authentication with the proxyhost using this method.  It is possible to send the password over to the proxy, but I don’t recommend that at all.      Are you able to log in to your proxy machine without any password? Is pageant working?